# Invalid activation token - problem with controller?

Tags: url, urlencode, .net-core-3.1

I have a really weird problem. Everything worked in previous version of .net core, but now in .net core 3.1 it does not.

So the thing is, after a user registers an account, I send him activation e-mail with activation code created like this:

```
var activationCode = await userMan.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(su);
```

Next I generate a http url which is formed like that:

```
http://localhost/api/users/activate?userId=1234&code=abc+860/def==
```

Now, note that userId is a valid GUID and my activation code is just example, because I really get a long one code. But what's important in this code - it has plus sings(+), slashes and ends with double equal sign.

Now I get the email with valid user guid and still VALID activation code. But, when I click this link and my UsersController starts, something bad happens. This is my activation method in UserController (part of code)

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("activate")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ActivateAccount([FromQuery] Guid userId, [FromQuery] string code)
    {
        if (userId == Guid.Empty || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(code))
            return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

And the weird thing is that the `code` parameter is invalid here. The value is just without plus signs. Instead it has spaces. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to URL Encode parameters. Some symbols can get stripped without that.
You can read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) about symbols and the procedure.

Correct URL for you will be:

```
http://localhost/api/users/activate?userId=1234&code=abc%2B860%2Fdef%3D%3D
```

And to generate correct URL, you can use [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode?view=netcore-3.1) before giving a URL to someone. Read the link as there are details that could be helpful. That is some common approach to encode URLs.

And [here](https://haacked.com/archive/2019/12/09/fun-with-url-encodings/) is some nice article, listing all or majority of approaches to do so, discussing on how to peak one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just did: var activationCode = await userMan.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(su);
activationCode = Uri.EscapeDataString(activationCode);

And now it works fine. Thank you very much for explanation and links.